# Review suspension message incorrectly refers to "questions" even when the incorrect review was of an answer

Tags: bug, review-suspension

A [recent Meta Stack Overflow post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407236/208273) showed the following review ban message:

[image: Screnshot of review ban message]

It says, in relevant part:

> The following tasks were handled incorrectly:
>
> - [/review/low-quality-posts/28864465](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/28864465)
>
> For these reviews in the *Low Quality Posts* review queue, the *Looks OK* action would have been more appropriate because nothing was wrong with these questions.

However, the linked review is of an *answer*, not a question.  The template should probably just say "posts" instead of "questions" (or perhaps "post(s)" since there could be only one, as was the case here).